# USB to parallel port converter for more than printers

Tags: usb

I sometimes need to tweak (python) software on a PC that doesn't have a parallel port yet the live system does and the software uses it.

I need some way to convince my system that it has a parallel port - ideally a USB to parallel port converter that would function at some level - but if not then just something that fakes it - so long as I can run the software without having to comment all the code that tries to access the parallel port.

All the parallel port to USB converters I've seen appear to only be for printers and don't fake a port.

I realize that even if it did work that the timing would not be precise as per a dedicated parallel port - I don't care about this though as its not being used to test that aspect of the software.

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for: https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~ygu/bastelecke/PC/USB2LPT/index.en.htm